# Data through JNI is not passing properly

Tags: java, android, c++, c, java-native-interface

I am using JNI to call the native C++ layer.

java layer

```
int res= recog(audioFilePath, grammarFilePath, contextID, subContextID);
```

C++ layer

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_uniphore_voice_recogniser_NuanceOfflineRecogniser_recog(JNIEnv *jenv, jobject jobj, jstring jaudioFilePath, 
                           jstring jgrammarFilePath, <br/>
                           jstring jcontextID, 
                           jstring jsubContext)
{

const char* _audioFilePath      = (char*)jenv->GetStringChars(jaudioFilePath, JNI_FALSE);
const char* _grammarFilePath    = (char*)jenv->GetStringChars(jgrammarFilePath, JNI_FALSE);
const char* _contextId          = (char*)jenv->GetStringChars(jcontextID, JNI_FALSE);
const char* _subContextId       = (char*)jenv->GetStringChars(jsubContext, JNI_FALSE);

std::wcout  << "audio file path: "  << _audioFilePath   <<" "<< std::strlen(_audioFilePath) <<std::endl
            << "grammar file path: "<< _grammarFilePath <<" "<<std::strlen(_grammarFilePath) << std::endl
            << "contextId: "        << _contextId       << std::endl
            << "subContextId: "     << _subContextId    << std::endl << std::endl;
```

I can see at java layer values is properly passed to the lower level but in c++ layer while printing that value in C++ layer I can see it is printing only first character of whole string.

suppose if audioFilePath I am passing like **"c:\test.wav"** I am getting print in c++ layer only like **c**

I am trying in visual studio 2013 and project character support I selected as Unicode support.

I am new to c++ environment, please help to get the reason for this one.

Comment: why it has android tag? also `char` is 1 byte and unicode needs 2 bytes ...

Answer (score 1):

According to [JNI docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) `GetStringChars` returns the unicode characters for the given string in a `jchar *` which is an `unsigned short *`. You cast it to a `char *`. When you use `cout` with a `char *` it expects a string in ASCII format with a null-terminator. You pass it a pointer to a string in unicode format, which has every other character `0` for plain ASCII characters. Hence why you only print the first character in the string.

Answer (score 0):

GetStringChars is not returning a pointer to single byte characters, but two byte, unicode characters

```
const jchar * GetStringChars(JNIEnv *env, jstring string,
jboolean *isCopy);

Returns a pointer to the array of Unicode characters of the string.
```

Instead, try

```
GetStringUTFChars
```

This will be null terminated also.

Comment: thanks using GetStringUTFChars has returned me the right result.

Comment: dont forget to make the answer correct which was most useful :)